# Cross correlation coefficient for 2 matrices (two 2d arrays)

Tags: matrices, correlation, computer-vision, pattern-matching

I'm trying to manually calculate cross correlation coefficient for 2 matrices. But I'm not sure how to apply the formula and how it works.
Here are my example matrices:

[Matrix 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkY3a.jpg)
[Matrix 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3VsP.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Behrouz

P.S. As you know, this method is used in 'template matching' in computer vision.

Comment: This page from mathworks (MATLAB) is providing some advice: https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html